# Read selected column from log file

Tags: php

can you help me to solve this problem.
I have a log file with columns inside it. I just want to read a column.

This is the sample log file :

2019-05-14 00:00:00 1558449 v7.41   33309
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1335564 v7.38   33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1584141 v7.34   39800
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1556654 v7.38   33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1456993 v7.39   33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1581138 v7.39   33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1224055 v7.39   33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1557900 v7.35   33309
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1576229 v7.39   33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1553292 v7.35   33309

I just need to read this 1558449 column.

The code I've tried is in this link:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-to-read-lines-from-text-file-into-a-table-format-in-PHP

Im expecting the output will just be like this :

1558449
1335564
1584141
1556654
1456993
1581138
1224055
1557900
1576229
1553292

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php, space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is :

- Open file
- Read line by line
- Explode line by delimiter space(" ") {Convert string to array}
- Get 3rd element of array (index 2)

Example

```
$fn = fopen("log.txt","r");
while(! feof($fn))  {
    $line = fgets($fn);
    $val = explode(" ", $line)[2];
    echo $val."<br>";
}
fclose($fn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey use regex to solve it.

First, read the file using `file_get_contents()` function of PHP. This function reads entire file into a string.
[Reads entire file into a string - PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Now using PHP `preg_match_all()` function, fetch whatever you want from string.
[PHP: preg_match_all - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

See:

```php
/**
$file = "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1558449 v7.41 33309
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1335564 v7.38 33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1584141 v7.34 39800
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1556654 v7.38 33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1456993 v7.39 33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1581138 v7.39 33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1224055 v7.39 33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1557900 v7.35 33309
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1576229 v7.39 33600
2019-05-14 00:00:00 1553292 v7.35 33309";
*/
$file = file($addressOfFile);
preg_match_all("/.*([0-9]{7}).*/", $file, $matches);
```

*Its result will be:*

```php
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(10) {
    [0] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1558449 v7.41 33309"
    [1] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1335564 v7.38 33600"
    [2] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1584141 v7.34 39800"
    [3] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1556654 v7.38 33600"
    [4] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1456993 v7.39 33600"
    [5] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1581138 v7.39 33600"
    [6] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1224055 v7.39 33600"
    [7] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1557900 v7.35 33309"
    [8] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1576229 v7.39 33600"
    [9] =>
    string(39) "2019-05-14 00:00:00 1553292 v7.35 33309"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(10) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "1558449"
    [1] =>
    string(7) "1335564"
    [2] =>
    string(7) "1584141"
    [3] =>
    string(7) "1556654"
    [4] =>
    string(7) "1456993"
    [5] =>
    string(7) "1581138"
    [6] =>
    string(7) "1224055"
    [7] =>
    string(7) "1557900"
    [8] =>
    string(7) "1576229"
    [9] =>
    string(7) "1553292"
  }
}
```

Now you can access what you want by `$matches[1]` which is an array.

Comment: Thanks man, but sorry I accidentally mention regex. I got no knowledge yet about regex. But thanks in advance